# How to appendChild custom component using React JS and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

I have some code like

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  let child = <ChildComponent {...props} />;
  if (condition) {
    const parent = document.GetElementById("parentId");
    //Here is a problem
    parent.appendChild(child);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div id="parentId"></div>
    </>
  );
};
export default ParentComponent;

const ChildComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div></div>
    </>
  );
};
export default ChildComponent;
```

I want to dynamically add child components multiple times but getting an error [image]

I am happy to do it in any way using Javascript or useRef.
Thanks!

Comment: The main problem is you shouldn't be mixing React with native DOM methods like that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using JSX to conditionally render the element instead? Even if you want to do it through native DOM methods, you have several issues: (1) you have a typo in your `document.GetElementById` (it should be lowercase 'g', (2) you are not waiting for the virtual DOM to be rendered (and be available in the real DOM) before appending it. See `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do conditional rendering in react is as follows:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="parentId">
        {condition && <ChildComponent {...props } />}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default ParentComponent;
```

You mentioned wanting to do it multiple times, though you didn't show an example of what you have in mind. You can create an array and fill it with however many child elements you want. For example:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [childCount, setChildCount] = useState(8);

  const children = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    if (condition) {
      children.push(<ChildComponent {...props } />);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div id="parentId">
        {children}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```